# Check the following code. Its related to the pointer to an array concept

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-to-array

Consider the following code

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int s[4][2] = 
    {  
        {20,1}, 
        {21,2}, 
        {22,3}, 
        {23,5}  
    };    
    int (*p)[2];
    int i,j,*pint;

    for( i=0;i<=3;i++)
    {
        p=&s[i];
        pint= (int *)p;

            for(j=0;j<=1;j++)
            { 
                printf("%d \n", *(pint + j));
            }
    }
}
```

The code basically creates a 2-D array, then creates a pointer to 1-D array. Then the pointer to the 1-D array is initialized with the code
p = &s[i];

The next line initializes a pointer to an integer 'pint'. 
pint = (int *)p;

**I was wondering why the following line of code doesn't work. It makes logical sense.
pint = p;**

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Does the pointer remain uninitialized? Does the printf not print what you expect?

Comment: Please copy and paste, don't retype! This line will not compile: `for(j=0;j<=;j++)`

Comment: What output do you expect and what output do you get ?

Answer (score 1):

`p` is type `int (*)[2]` which is related to `s` and indeed any assignment

```
p = s + (int)x;
```

will work. But `pint` is of type `int *`. Although you are casting `p` to that type you are pushing it for undefined behaviour.

What you probably want is

```
int i,j,*pint;

for( i=0;i<=3;i++)
{
    pint = s[i]; // pint points to the two ints in row i

        for(j=0;j<=1;j++) // i assume you missed the one here
        { 
            printf("%d \n", *(pint + j));
        }
}
```

Comment: I think it is *constraint violation* instead of *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Could you tell me what exactly we mean when we write (int*) p?

Comment: `(int *)p` means casting `p` to `int *` type.

Answer (score 0):

It will not compile.

```
 for(j=0;j<=;j++)
            ^Missing the limit
```

It should be

```
 for(j=0;j < 2;j++)
```

See the working code here: http://ideone.com/CvNlxG

Answer (score 0):

In C the value of an array is a pointer to its first element.  You have:

```
    int s[4][2];
    int (*p)[2];
    int i,j,*pint;
```

So let's look at the types in your expressions:

```
        p=&s[i]; /* & here is unsafe, it's a trap, see at end. */
```

Left hand side, pointer to array of two ints, right hand side, exactly the same.

```
        pint= (int *)p;
```

Right hand side is forcibly converted, no need to examine further.

```
                printf("%d \n", *(pint + j));
```

pint is pointer to int, so pint+j points j ints past what pint points at, * that is an int.

which all work, and you want

```
    pint = p;
```

which doesn't.  Left hand side is pointer to int, right hand side is pointer to array of two ints, see above.

So you can do

```
    pint = *p;
```

or

```
    pint = p[0];
```

which has *exactly* the same semantics -- in fact, `p[j]` is *defined* to be `*(p+j)`, which works, because of the array value semantics.

Or you could use the

```
    pint = &p[0];
```

construction I flagged above as a trap.  It's the same as the previous expression, *here*, because of the rule, but it breaks an extremely commonly-used equivalence:

```
int *P = p[0];
```

works for *all* of the following declarations of `p`:

```
int p[1][1];
int (*p)[1];
int **p;
```

but `&p[0]` doesn't, and the breakage is more likely than you might expect, C programmers simply expect that code built to work with fixed-size arrays also works with variable-sized ones just by changing declarations.

Answer (score -3):

`p` is of type `int (*)[2]`.
`pint` is of type `int*`.

They are two different types, which is why the statement `pint = p;` will not work.

Comment: This is wrong. `p` is of type `int (*)[2]`. Please do not confuse that with `int **`

Comment: Fixed. And how is it misleading? `int *[2]` and `int*` are 2 different types and cannot be set to be equal without a cast.

Comment: @Dr.Tower: It's still wrong. As SergeyL. said, it's `int (*)[2]`, not `int*[2]`. The former is a pointer to an array. The latter is an array of pointers.